# Deciding whether this integral is convergent or divergent: $\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{\sqrt {x}}}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Decide if the following integral is convergent or divergent. If it is convergent evaluate the integral. $$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\sqrt {x}}}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm dx$$

I evaluated the integral, but I could not decide via comparison test whether the integral is convergent or divergent.

Comment: Please include your work so we can help you.

Comment: If you evaluated it, wouldn't that be proof enough whether it converges or diverges?

Comment: But it says first decide then evaluate so I tried to compare this function with 1/x^(1/2) , but it is greater and divergent but I couldnt find smaller funstion than given

Comment: @Pumpkin For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^{\sqrt{x}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{0.5n}}{n!}$$
$$\implies e^{\sqrt{x}}>x$$
$$\therefore \sqrt{x}e^{\sqrt{x}}>x^{1.5}$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}e^{\sqrt{x}}}<x^{-1.5}$$
Since $\int_1^{\infty} x^{-1.5} dx$ is convergent then the $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}e^{\sqrt{x}}}$ is convergent.

Comment: The last step should likely read $<x^{-1.5}$ and the integral as well, which would actually make it convergent :-) since $\int_0^\infty x^{1.5} dx = + \infty$...

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Indeed you're right!

Comment: The integral that John is showing to be convergent does not seem to be the integral that Pumpkin is talking about...

Comment: @ireallydonknow The editor changed the integral incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Try the transformation: $y=\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: How can I apply comparison test with that substitution?

Comment: @Pumpkin if you sub correctly your integral becomes $\int e^{-y}$...

Comment: With the substitution you do not need to apply any test, as you can find the precise value of the integral.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=\sqrt{x}$ Then, $2du=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$. $\sqrt{1} = 1$, and $\sqrt{\infty}$ should be $\infty$ when we take limits.
So, the integral becomes $2\int_1^{\infty} e^{-u} du = -2e^{-u}|_1^{\infty} = \frac{2}{e}$, again, when we use limits. Thus, the integral converges as our value is finite.